# How to stick a button to one place on the document?

Tags: css

I need to make button to stay in one place while sizing the window(making it responsive). So as I go to lower resolution I need it to be at the bottom of the FORM i have. I have tried setting form relative and button absolute and then doing bottom 0 but its not working. I also tried setting top to 80% of the page. Html,body are 100% width and height.

```css
Form {
  border: 5px solid gray;
  padding: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(222, 164, 1, 0.3);
  position: relative;
}

button {
  background-color: darkslateblue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  margin: 0;
  width: 7%;
  height: 5%;
  color: darkturquoise;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <form action="" id="MojaForma" name="MojaForma">
    <label for="imejl">E-mail</label>
    <input type="email" id="imejl" name="imejl" required placeholder="example@example.com">
    <br>
    <label for="Broj">Broj Telefona</label>
    <input type="text" id="broj" name="broj" required placeholder="+38160/12-34-567">
    <br>
    <label for="naziv" id="nazivlabela">Izaberite naziv filma:</label>
    <select name="naziv" id="naziv" required>
      <option value="Spiderman: No way home">Spiderman : No way home</option>
      <option value="The Mist">The mist</option>
      <option value="Love and the other drugs">Love and the other drugs</option>
      <option value="Baby driver 1">Baby driver 1</option>
      <option value="Hobbit: The unexpected journey">Hobbit : The unexpected journey</option>
      <option value="6 Underground">6 Underground</option>
      <option value="The circle">The circle</option>
      <option value="Lord of the rings: Fellowship of the ring">Lord of the rings: Fellowship of the ring</option>
      <option value="Se7en">Se7en</option>
      <option value="Spenser confidental">Spenser confidental</option>
      <option value="Ride Along 1">Ride along 1</option>
      <option value="The Ridiculous 6">The Ridiculous 6</option>
    </select>
    <br>

    <input type="radio" id="deset" name="time" checked value="10:00">
    <label for="deset" id="deset" class="vreme">10:00</label>

    <input type="radio" id="dva" name="time" value="14:00">
    <label for="dva" class="vreme">14:00</label>

    <input type="radio" id="pet" name="time" value="17:00">
    <label for="pet" class="vreme">17:00</label>

    <input type="radio" id="sedam" name="time" value="19:00">
    <label for="sedam" class="vreme">19:00</label>
    <br>
    <label for="karte">Broj karata</label>
    <input type="number" min="1" id="karte" name="karte" value="1" required>
  </form>
  <button id="predaj" onclick="provera()">Posalji</button>
  <a href="tabela.html">Tabela</a>
</center>
```

theres the HTML its a form form is relative

Comment: Provide your HTML. `80%` are relative to what?

Comment: @cloned I have added it

Comment: @cloned Relative to the page? Form is the only thing in the body